# Emberjs bindings without static path?

Tags: ember.js

I have two ember objects available in a function, but I cant seem to figure out how to create a binding between them, since I cant reference them via a static path. The objects are referenced to as `var a`and `var b`in the javascript function.

How to create a binding between two objects when I can't reference one of them like `App.controller.content` or similar?

Or alternatively; can I reference to a specific ember object in a ArrayControllers content via some static path? I have tried many variations of the getPath method on both objects but cant seem to get it to return something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All paths have to be relative to "this" (whatever the object is, or what was in the apply) or as you stated, a global path.  But there is nothing stopping you from setting relative paths once you are in the function you mentioned.

```
a.set('b': b);

a.set('someMethod', function(){
    return this.getPath('b.methodName');
}.property('b.methodName'));
```

Once they have reference to each other, you can add relative paths to your hearts content.  I would prefer to do this over creating a method with relative scope, so you don't miss any updating values.

I created a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/uFKwz/) to show you what I mean.  I would normally have created a View etc, but was trying to keep it to only a few lines.

Now that being said, I feel like you should be able to bind directly between objects by setting a _to or _from on a Binding.  But looking through that code, it seems like everything is relative & path based.  Maybe the transformation stuff will change in the 1.0 release of the framework.

Comment: ahh, so I can use relative paths just like that. Great info!